# Organising LUIS intents to apart classes

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'am struggling with splitting LUIS intents implementations to apart classes. I'm now putting all of code for LUIS intents in a LuisDialog class which makes my code not clear to read (one thousands of code for sure in a single class).
So what can I do to split each of LUIS intents implementation to apart classes.

I want to handel "CreateTodo" intent further in an apart class and keep LuisDialog class just simple and clear to read. Which syntax can i use for?
Context.Call? I saw a similar issue that using partial class helps. So can anyone show a sample pattern for me? Thanks in advance.:)

```
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)

    [LuisIntent("CreateTodo")]
    public async Task CreateTodoIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult 
    result)

    //...more intents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using v3 of the botframework. So you could either use `context.Call` or `context.Forward`. `context.Call` will start the new dialog and then wait for a new message to be received. `context.Forward` will send the current message to the new dialog.

If you have a dialog called `CreateTodoDialog` and you want to start that dialog, you would use `context.Call(new CreateTodoDialog(), AfterCreateTodoDialog)` where `AfterCreateTodoDialog` is what you want to run after your new dialog.

The way I setup my luis dialog is to have a method for each intent and then perform the logic for extracting any luis entities if there are any, then either call or forward to a dialog for each intent. I then had a single method that I used for after the child dialogs.

Comment: Hi. I am trying to use either context.call or context.forward, but I still do not understand how to do with my CreateTodoDialog. Should it also implements LuisDialog<object>? Can I handel entities in CreateTodoDialgo class if there any entities or should I do that in LuisDialog class? Can you put some sample code, please? Thanks a lot.